# Fetch Facebook Friends list that not installed my app

Tags: ios, facebook-friends

i want to fectch fb friends list that have not used or installed my app.
and is there any other way that i fetch Friend unique id.
because withour friend id i can't send invitation to use my app or game.
**please help me.**

> . I have used FacebookSDk 4.0 and Graph API 2.3..both are latest.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using the `taggable_friends` endpoint: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.0/user/taggable_friends

Comment: how do you get the friend's id? the id returned here is a long string that I'm not sure what it is.

Comment: Facebook no longer allows developers to access the IDs of friends that don't use their app: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/upgrading